# how to paste content of clipboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, paste

I want to copy/paste some content from one div to another
In the example below clicking on `paste` button expected result in `target` div is - `<p>lorem ipsum</p>`
but simply - nothing happens

```js
$('.btncopy').on('click', function(){
    let a = $('.story').html().trim();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(a);
  console.log(a);  // it works
});
$('.btnpaste').on('click', function(){
    let a = navigator.clipboard.readText();
  console.log(a);  // doesn't work
    $('.target').text(a); 
});
```

```css
.story, .target{min-height:25px; background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btncopy'>COPY</button>
<button class='btnpAste'>PASTE</button>
<div class='story'><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
<br>
<div class='target'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readText()` (just as `writeText`) [returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText), you need to await for it. So in your case it will be something like this:

```js
navigator.clipboard.readText().then(function(a) {
  console.log(a);  // works
  $('.target').text(a); 
});
```

However if you try it in the SO snippet runner (or any other JS fiddler online) it will not work due to permission restrictions.